# passing geojson data from flask app to javascript to be used in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, python, flask, leaflet, geojson

OK, I have a map on a webpage using flask, python, html, javascript.  My problem is that when I hard code the geoJson data, it works fine.  When I pass the geoJson data from the python script to the Javascript to be used in leaflet, it does not work.  I am not getting any errors other then the visual error of no data.

I am using python to read data from a csv file, and creating a geoJson file using modified version of:

> http://www.andrewdyck.com/how-to-convert-csv-data-to-geojson/
>   Thank you Andrew

Here is the JavaScript used to call the python method.  It is called with an onClick function call in the html:

```
function getValues(){
    $.ajax({
       data: chks}, // there is data passed, but it doesn't effect this issue
       type : 'POST',
       url : '/process'
})
  .done(function(data){  // its this passed data that is not being read correctly.  When I hard code this with the geojson found below, it works great.
      var markOptions = {
          radius:8,
          ... };
      var pntslay = L.geoJson(data, {
          pointsToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
             return L.circleMarker(latlng, markOptions);
}}).addTo(map);
```

Here is my modified python and flask code:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    data = request.form['chks']
    rawData = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'rb'), dialect='excel')
# the template. where data from the csv will be formatted to geojson
    template = \
    ''' \
    { "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [%s,%s]},
    "properties" : { "name" : "%s", "value" : "%s"}
    },
    '''
# the head of the geojson file
    output = \
    ''' \
    { "type" : "Feature Collection",
    {"features" : [
    '''
# loop through the csv by row skipping the first
    iter = 0
    for row in rawData:
        iter += 1
        if iter >= 2:
            id = row[0]
            lat = row[1]
            lon = row[2]
    output += template % (row[2], row[1], row[0])
 # the tail of the geojson file
    output += \
    ''' \
    ]};
    '''            
    return output
```

Here is the geoJson file.  When I hard code this, it works.  When I use the passed data from the python script, it does not.  The hardcoded data was copied from the output in firefox firebug.

```
var geojsonPnts = {
    "type": "Feature Collection",
    "feature" : [
        {"type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
             "type" : "Point",
             "coordinates" : [ -86.27, 32.36 ]},
        "properties" : { "name" : "some place" }
      },
       {"type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
             "type" : "Point",
             "coordinates" : [ -105.45, 40.63 ]},
        "properties" : { "name" : "some other place" }
      },
      ]};
```

I am not sure why the passed data is not working.  Please excuse typos and fat fingers errors.  I am not able to copy and paste my working code to here.

Comment: Since you mention you have the .CSV file, I wonder if you've already tried [Leaflet Omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore). It's really easy to use, you can see an example [here](https://cccruzr.github.io/maps/docs/masacres.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have an extra semicolon (`;`) at the end of your python output.

Also make sure the `data` you pass to `L.geoJSON` factory is already a proper JavaScript object. You can output a `typeof data` to check that, for example.

If it is still a string, simply convert it first using `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: I have searched for the extra semicolon as suggested by ghybs with no luck in finding it. I did the jsonify as outlined in other question, but that only gives me a network error signifying an overloaded server (not possible at this time) or an error in the code, which I cant find. When I - return output - it sends a string which I can see with and alert. When I - return jsonify(output) - I get the network error. Yes, I included jsonify to my import